# Java - Creating a httprequest the uses the header information from previous request

Tags: java, url, post

I got some sample code from the net here:
http://www.javadb.com/sending-a-post-request-with-parameters-from-a-java-class

That works fine. It sets the relevant headers in the response. However, what if I wanted to visit another url on the same site with those headers? If I create another URL object the session is lost. How do I maintain the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going at a pretty low level, unless that's intentional, you might want to consider using a library such as Apache Commons HttpClient, which will handle cookie management for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question offhand but you might want to consider using [HttpUnit](http://www.httpunit.org).  It makes a lot of tasks of hitting a server easy (such as authentication, providing form input, etc.).  As always there are trade offs.  Perhaps it would be too heavy a client for your needs...  but it will allow you to maintain a session with the server.

EDIT: On second thought: [Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) might be better.  I believe it is what HttpUnit uses under the hood anyway.